# Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database

Tags: php

I get this error while connecting to database with php-class:
when try to connecting to database I get this:

> Warning: mysqli_connect() [function.mysqli-connect]: (42000/1044):
>   Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'pixels' in
>   D:\AppServ\www\my\classes\db.class.php on line 15

db.class.php :

```
    class DBclass{
    private $servern,$username,$password,$dbname,$connect;
    public function connectDB(){
        $this->servern = $this->get_servern();
        $this->username = $this->get_username();
        $this->password = $this->get_password();
        $this->dbname   = $this->get_dbname();

        $this->connect = mysqli_connect($this->servern,$this->username,$this->password,$this->dbname);
        if(!$this->connect){
            echo 'Error : Fail to connect to database !!';
        }
    }
//=========================================================//
    public function set_servern($host){
        $this->servern = $servern;
    }

    public function set_username($user){
        $this->username = $username;
    }

    public function set_password($pass){
        $this->password = $servern;
    }

    public function set_dbname($dbname){
        $this->dbname = $dbname;
    }
//===========================================================//
    private function get_servern(){
        return $this->servern;
    }

    private function get_username(){
        return $this->username;
    }

    private function get_password(){
        return $this->password;
    }

    private function get_dbname(){
        return $this->dbname;
    }
}
```

connect.php :

```
include('./classes/db.class.php');
$con = new DBclass();
    $con->set_servern('localhost');
    $con->set_username('root');
    $con->set_password('root');
    $con->set_dbname('pixels');

    $con->connectDB();
```

note : I am  using appserv

> AppServ 2.6.0 
>  Apache 2.2.8 
>  PHP 6.0.0-dev 
>  MySQL 6.0.4-alpha
>   phpMyAdmin-2.10.3

Comment: php6? You're from the future?

Comment: You are on PHP6? Who wins the superbowl in 2014, and what's the final score? Because you must be from the future!!!

Comment: AppServ 2.6.0
Apache 2.2.8
PHP 6.0.0-dev
MySQL 6.0.4-alpha
phpMyAdmin-2.10.3

Comment: @ircmaxell all is lost. Now we know that in future people will invent time machine. And this is the least evil consequence from that (I guess that time machine was written on PHP)

Comment: @ircmaxell: If he's from the future then he should already know the answer to his question.

Comment: @user3254394 you're using a build from 2008. You should consider using something other than AppServ as it's probably an old deprecated project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix your code like this:

```
 public function set_username($username){
        $this->username = $username;
    }
```

Comment: And what about the same mistake being done in `set_servern()` and `set_password()`?